# Hide mat-tab content behind footer

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular 5, Angular Material

I want to implement a `<mat-tab-group>` with two `<mat-tab>` Elements, but the content in my tab is alway's before the sticky footer.

I already tried too set the z-index.

**Mat-Tab**

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      Tab Title
    </ng-template>
    <div>
      lorem Impsu
    </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**Footer**

```
.bottom-footer{
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

<div class="bottom-footer">
  <div>Footer Content</div>
</div>
```

Stackbliz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-hide-tab , move the console up to see the problem

Comment: Add more details.

Comment: If you can, provide a working example in stackblitz, plunkr, etc when you replicate the behavior you're facing; share some of your actual code as well

Comment: sry, now I provided some Example code to rebuild the behavior

Comment: Have you tried setting a `margin-bottom` on your `mat-tab-group` elements to compensate the height of the `footer`?

Comment: I already tried to set a margin-bottom, this had no effective change;

The Title of the mat-tab is also in the foreground

Comment: Can you replicate this in stackblitz? or share more of your code structure so we can try to replicate it with you code?

Comment: What are the parent containers of the tab group and the footer? Which is first in the DOM? Show _all_ relevant code.

Comment: I needed some time to build a Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-hide-tab

Comment: Ok, so, the behavior you expect is the `footer` to be on top of the content in the tabs when they overlap?

Comment: yep the footer should always be in the foreground

Comment: Try adding `z-index: 1` to the footer, worked just fine on you stackblitz

Comment: it work's, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, a `z-index` would solve the issue you have easily; I would imagine you might've had a syntax error, causing the class to not apply correctly. Also, you should consider using the `footer` HTML5 tag instead of a `div` to define a footer section.

```
.footer {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1
}
```